# spreadsheet revision history

Tags: timestamp, report, block, revision-history

I have been thinking that could be of great help for me to have a "revision history" easily/offline or "time arranged" of the changes made on the working cells.

When user changes values or information on a cell at 4pm (originally given info at 12am) it may causes "unnoticed" errors.

I don't see a way to block a cell after user has enter information

in other words: The cell should be "Time stamped" (out the user's sight.) then at the en of the day, me having a report of any "time discrepancies" , ie cell b2 time stamped at 10 am, was again changed at 4pm.

Or I don't know, other thing it could be useful feature could be: cell 2 was changed at 10 am. Then, at 10:10 block the cell that only the Administrator would be able to unblock.

Thanks so much

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, what spreadsheet are you using?

Comment: well, yes is a programming question. I don't see any other way to do it. But of course if you have any other ideas I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: I am using a google spreadsheet